# pl-sql optimizing to calculate bewteen two transaction time

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

main question is how could I write optimized query to calculate time stamp between two transaction. Actually there is gigantic number of transactions in one table and I want to calculate time stamp between last inserted record and latest one. So could you help me to figure it up what is the best way to handle it please

I have used lag functions to find latest transaction and then minus the new inserted record time to latest, but it consume a lot of time

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired output for it as long as the difference between *last inserted* and *last* is not very clear. And please share your current query and its *actual* execution plan (which may be collected by `dbms_xplan.display_cursor`, for example)

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Example is based on sample Scott's schema whose tables certainly don't have *gigantic number of transactions*, but that should be enough to illustrate the approach. (All dates are in `DD.MM.YYYY` format).

```
SQL> select ename, hiredate
  2  from emp
  3  order by hiredate desc;

ENAME      HIREDATE
---------- ----------
ADAMS      12.01.1983   --> that's "new inserted record"
SCOTT      09.12.1982   --> that's "last inserted"
MILLER     23.01.1982
FORD       03.12.1981
<snip>

14 rows selected.
```

Difference between those two dates is (in number of days)

```
SQL> select date '1983-01-12' - date '1982-12-09' as diff from dual;

      DIFF
----------
        34
```

Query *sorts* rows by `hiredate` in descending order, using the `rank` analytic function. It means that `rn = 1` represents "new inserted record", while `rn = 2` represents "last inserted" one. Then subtract values to get the result:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select ename,
  3            hiredate,
  4            rank() over (order by hiredate desc) rn
  5    from emp
  6   )
  7  select a.hiredate - b.hiredate as diff
  8  from temp a cross join temp b
  9  where a.rn = 1
 10    and b.rn = 2;

      DIFF
----------
        34

SQL>
```

---

In your case:

```
with temp as
  (select insert_time,
          row_number() over (order by insert_time desc) rn
  from your_table
 )
select a.insert_time - b.insert_time
from your_table a cross join your_table b
where a.rn = 1 
  and b.rn = 2;
```

It would benefit from

- index on `insert_time`
- regularly collected statistics on table (or - even better - the whole schema)

---

Alternatively, perhaps you could improve the whole thing *significantly* if you created a new table that contains only those two dates:

```
SQL> create table latest_diff
  2    (new_insert  date,
  3     last_insert date
  4    );

Table created.
```

Insert initial record (so that you'd have a *starting point*):

```
SQL> insert into latest_diff (new_insert, last_insert) values (date '1983-01-12', date '1982-12-09');

1 row created.
```

Then, create a simple trigger on your table (it is `emp` in my example) which sets date values. That trigger should do its job in *no time*:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_emp
  2    before insert on emp
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    update latest_diff set
  6      last_insert = new_insert,
  7      new_insert  = :new.hiredate;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

OK, let's try it: initial data shows difference we already calculated (34 days):

```
SQL> select * from latest_diff;

NEW_INSERT LAST_INSER
---------- ----------
12.01.1983 09.12.1982

SQL> select new_insert - last_insert diff from latest_diff;

      DIFF
----------
        34
```

Inserting a new record into table:

```
SQL> insert into emp (empno, hiredate) values (1, date '1983-01-18');

1 row created.
```

`latest_diff` table is modified (trigger did that):

```
SQL> select * from latest_diff;

NEW_INSERT LAST_INSER
---------- ----------
18.01.1983 12.01.1983
```

Finding a difference is really simple and fast as you don't have to *scroll* through that *gigantic* table every time, but fetch data from a single-row table.

```
SQL> select new_insert - last_insert diff from latest_diff;

      DIFF
----------
         6

SQL>
```

Comment: Just a remark: `where insert_time is not null` or `not null` constraint is required for the index (if any) to be used. And possibly `max(insert_time) - min(insert_time) ... where rn <= 2` to have a single access to the table

Comment: I guess that INSERT_TIME won't be NULL. Otherwise, there's no point in that calculation at all. As of "MAX - MIN" - sure, good idea, thank you, @astentx!

Comment: It definitely will not be `null`, but it may be enforced by the app design, not by DBMS. So an optimizer should know this and therefore has an explicit `not null` result for the query: by means of a constraint of by the (artificial) filter. Just to illustrate this: https://dbfiddle.uk/Y_6XMm_P